# Postfix SMTP server gets "550 Requested mail action not taken: Invalid IP"

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, spf

I have a SMTP server named smtp-ca.mdpi.com and when sending emails to some specific chinese email domains, I am getting back:

```
550 Requested mail action not taken: Invalid IP<64.15.147.140> (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

I have an SPF set in the TXT of the domain. The rDSN is working fine.

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the postconf -n configuration

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1 10.10.0.10
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 102400000
myhostname = smtp-ca.mdpi.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.10.0.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

Comment: It's hard to guess why these chinese email domains are rejecting your SMTP session. And it's even harder to guess if you don't provide your current configuration. Please show the output of `postconf -n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct and i have checked your Forward and Reverse entries. That look ok. The problem is that you don't know which SPAM-System and RBL the recipient use.

So its possible that they use a special RBL-List and you are blocked on that list for example. There are a lot of possibilities but i think your configuration is ok.

Perhaps you can analyse your logs and you get some more informations.